# How to pass touch event to another view under tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a scenario where I overlapped a view(`pageViewController` inside the view) with a `uitableview` with an offset of 130, and that `uitableview` is Transparent, only cells will be scrolled and visible.

My requirement is within this offset place of 130, I want to pass touch events to the view(`pageViewController`) which is below the `uitableview` and that view is not a superview(It is a sibling view) of table view but I overlapped it with tableview.

So is it possible to pass touch (Horizontal Swiping Event) to the view which is below the `uitableview` in the transparent area (Offset Area of 130); if yes, what I have to do for this?

[image: This is where I need to pass touch (swipe) event to the page controller which is back of the tableview]

Comment: provide the screenshot of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: (Downvoting with apologies for requesting urgency; we try to discourage that here. All questions are of equal importance, and are answered at the leisure of volunteers).

Comment: Hi I have used hitTest method also but that method is not calling. Is there any alternate way to handle this  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *lots* of options for controlling how touch events and scrolling interact in iOS. You can override `hitTest`, you can use delegate messages sent to gesture recognizers to say which combinations of recognizers should fire when, etc. Without seeing your problem in detail it's hard to say which is best... and even then, you might say it's partly a matter of style. (At first blush, though, I'd guess that overriding `hitTest` to return different views at different times might be it.)

I'd recommend watching the WWDC 2014 video on [Advanced Scrollviews and Touch Handling Techniques](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-235/). That talk works through solving some problem that sound almost exactly like yours, so you'll almost certainly find a good solution in there. And lots of other tips that might be helpful elsewhere in your app. (Actually, if you have the time, I'd recommend watching the UIScrollView-themed sessions from the past *several* years' WWDCs... the so-called "Josh & Eliza Show" has always been full of cool demos and useful insights.)

Comment: Hi I used hitTest methods but it is not calling that method. And I'm attaching an image what is my requirement is, table view is filled the whole view controller's view but i used background color for tableview and tableview cell as clear color. So it it not visible and below that I have banner view controller as you can see in provided image. So my requirement is if I swipe  on the empty space where you can see image(horse) touch should work for that pageview controller. So how can I achieve this ? Please check the image for reference

Comment: Hi I'm waiting for your reply on this I have used hitTest methods but it wont works for me. Can you help me out in this