# How to pass touch event to another view(pageViewController) under tableview?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Hi I asked this question and as a reference I gave Image also. My requirement is :  in this below image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogdvk.png),I have a scenario where I overlapped a view('pageViewController' inside the view) with a tableview with an offset of 130, and that tableview is Transparent, only cells will be scrolled and visible. My requirement is within this offset place of 130, I want to pass touch events to the view(pageViewController) which is below the tableview and that view is not a superview(It is a sibling view) of table view but I overlapped it with tableview.

So is it possible to pass touch (Horizontal Swiping Event) to the view which is below the tableview in the transparent area (Offset Area of 130); if yes, what I have to do for this?

Here Is my previous question : [How to pass touch event to another view under tableview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002738/how-to-pass-touch-event-to-another-view-under-tableview)

[[image: Home Screen]]

Comment: Please elaborate on why you've created almost the same question while the original has an accepted answer. The way SO works is that you collect reputation by helping the others, then you can spend it to start a bounty for your own questions and attract attention to them. What you did here looks like a duplicate. If you have a question regarding use of a particular method to implement what you want, add more details about this specific problem, otherwise I suggest you collect a little rep and start a bounty on the original question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass touch event to another view under tableview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34002738/how-to-pass-touch-event-to-another-view-under-tableview)

Comment: Actually I have added one image to this question but i didn't get the response so i created the new one. And I don't know how to start a bounty for my question so i did this

Comment: You need to earn 75 rep to be able to start spending it on bounties for your questions, check the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) for details. Setting a bounty is locked until 48 hours after the last edit though. If you want to get a helpful answer, adding the code that you tried to use often makes it easier for the other to help you, so consider doing that as well. It isn't too uncommon not to receive any response for such a question, either try to improve it or work on setting a bounty (which is not a guarantee to get an answer too).

Comment: Ok Thank you.. but i dont have 75 rep, i have only 27 now, and how can i get answer for my previous question now ? Its an urgent requirement for me and I'm not getting the response.No one is giving answer, What I have to do now ?

Comment: SO is not a place to find answers urgently, you can only make the question more appealing to be answered [as described here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Bounty is not *the* solution to get any of your questions answered too. If you don't find an answer this way, I guess you'll have to adapt and change the requirements (or hire somebody to do what you need).